# kube-proxy fails with CrashLoopBackOff in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am running k8s using minikube version v1.18.0 on Ubuntu 20. But kube-proxy fails with CrashLoopBackOff status. What could be the issue? I am using 1.18 version for k8s server and client with minikube. I tried reinstalling the cluster but the issue is persistent. logs are attached for get pod and describe pod.

```
/home/ravi> kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-gtsl7           0/1     Running            0          10m   172.17.0.2     minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running            0          10m   192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running            0          10m   192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running            0          10m   192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-d5dqf                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          10m   192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running            0          10m   192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system   storage-provisioner                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          11m   192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
/home/ravi>
/home/ravi>


/home/ravi>kubectl describe pod -n kube-system  kube-proxy-d5dqf
Name:                 kube-proxy-d5dqf
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000001000
Priority Class Name:  system-node-critical
Node:                 minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:           Fri, 13 May 2022 14:08:26 +0530
Labels:               controller-revision-hash=5bdc57b48f
                      k8s-app=kube-proxy
                      pod-template-generation=1
Annotations:          <none>
Status:               Running
IP:                   192.168.49.2
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.49.2
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/kube-proxy
Containers:
  kube-proxy:
    Container ID:  docker://dc1554848405254d1ba463fc4ae2ec98fb7e2db1472d3b143b71256dcb7812c3
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.18.20
    Image ID:      docker://sha256:27f8b8d51985f755cfb3ffea424fa34865cc0da63e99378d8202f923c3c5a8ba
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy
      --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf
      --hostname-override=$(NODE_NAME)
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Fri, 13 May 2022 14:19:30 +0530
      Finished:     Fri, 13 May 2022 14:19:30 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  7
    Environment:
      NODE_NAME:   (v1:spec.nodeName)
    Mounts:
      /lib/modules from lib-modules (ro)
      /run/xtables.lock from xtables-lock (rw)
      /var/lib/kube-proxy from kube-proxy (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-proxy-token-z2nb4 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-proxy:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      kube-proxy
    Optional:  false
  xtables-lock:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /run/xtables.lock
    HostPathType:  FileOrCreate
  lib-modules:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /lib/modules
    HostPathType:  
  kube-proxy-token-z2nb4:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  kube-proxy-token-z2nb4
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:     
                 CriticalAddonsOnly
                 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/network-unavailable:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute
                 node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute
                 node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  15m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/kube-proxy-d5dqf to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     13m (x5 over 15m)     kubelet, minikube  Container image "k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.18.20" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    13m (x5 over 15m)     kubelet, minikube  Created container kube-proxy
  Normal   Started    13m (x5 over 15m)     kubelet, minikube  Started container kube-proxy
  Warning  BackOff    5m22s (x49 over 15m)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container
/home/ravi>


/home/ravi>kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.0", GitCommit:"9e991415386e4cf155a24b1da15becaa390438d8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-25T14:58:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.20", GitCommit:"1f3e19b7beb1cc0110255668c4238ed63dadb7ad", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:51:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
/home/ravi>


/home/ravi/>kubectl logs -n kube-system  kube-proxy-d5dqf  
W0513 10:01:01.652298       1 server_others.go:559] Unknown proxy mode "", assuming iptables proxy
I0513 10:01:01.673427       1 node.go:136] Successfully retrieved node IP: 192.168.49.2
I0513 10:01:01.673482       1 server_others.go:186] Using iptables Proxier.
I0513 10:01:01.673968       1 server.go:583] Version: v1.18.20
I0513 10:01:01.674955       1 conntrack.go:100] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max' to 131072
F0513 10:01:01.675040       1 server.go:497] open /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max: permission denied
/home/ravi>
```

Comment: According to the issue [github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11418](http://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11418) this will be fixed with the minikube v1.21.0 + version. Can you upgrade the version and check if the issue gets resolved.